# How do I run Rake tasks within a Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, rake, command-line-interface

I have a `Rakefile` with a Rake task that I would normally call from the command line:

```
rake blog:post Title
```

I'd like to write a Ruby script that calls that Rake task multiple times, but the only solution I see is shelling out using `` (backticks) or `system`.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

from [timocracy.com](http://web.archive.org/web/20090412040557/http://timocracy.com:80/articles/2008/02/21/calling-invoking-rails-rake-tasks-from-within-ruby-for-testing-try-2):

```
require 'rake'

def capture_stdout
  s = StringIO.new
  oldstdout = $stdout
  $stdout = s
  yield
  s.string
ensure
  $stdout = oldstdout
end

Rake.application.rake_require 'metric_fetcher', ['../../lib/tasks']
results = capture_stdout {Rake.application['metric_fetcher'].invoke}
```

Comment: With Rails 3.1 the rake/rdoctask has been deprecated and tasks/rails is missing. The above works just fine with just the first require statement.

Comment: For changing stdout, I suggest saving the original stream via `#dup`, then `#reopen` to a `Tempfile` which is read after reopening to the original. Merely assigning `$stdout` won't work if the task uses the `STDOUT` constant, or runs an external program.

Comment: Be aware that `rake_require` always joins the given path with each path from the `$LOAD_PATH` array and checks for existence of a file. So the first argument should be a **relative path**. It will be treated as relative even if it contains a leading slash (or backslash on non-Unix systems).

Answer (score 23):

This works with Rake version 10.0.3:

```
require 'rake'
app = Rake.application
app.init
# do this as many times as needed
app.add_import 'some/other/file.rake'
# this loads the Rakefile and other imports
app.load_rakefile

app['sometask'].invoke
```

As knut said, use `reenable` if you want to invoke multiple times.

Comment: Hi @JasonFB, you can access the gem with something like `app.add_import "#{Gem::Specification.find_by_name('statesman').gem_dir}/lib/tasks/statesman.rake"`

Comment: somehow my rake task is executing twice . 
i have
puts "hello" in rake task 

and hello is printing twice...

Answer (score 17):

You can use `invoke` and `reenable` to execute the task a second time.

Your example call `rake blog:post Title` seems to have a parameter. This parameter can be used as a parameter in `invoke`:

Example:

```
require 'rake'
task 'mytask', :title do |tsk, args|
  p "called #{tsk} (#{args[:title]})"
end



Rake.application['mytask'].invoke('one')
Rake.application['mytask'].reenable
Rake.application['mytask'].invoke('two')
```

Please replace `mytask` with `blog:post` and instead the task definition you can `require` your rakefile.

This solution will write the result to stdout - but you did not mention, that you want to suppress output.

---

Interesting experiment:

You can call the `reenable` also inside the task definition. This allows a task to reenable himself.

Example:

```
require 'rake'
task 'mytask', :title do |tsk, args|
  p "called #{tsk} (#{args[:title]})"
  tsk.reenable  #<-- HERE
end

Rake.application['mytask'].invoke('one')
Rake.application['mytask'].invoke('two')
```

The result (tested with rake 10.4.2):

```
"called mytask (one)"
"called mytask (two)"
```

Comment: @JasonFB Do you have an example why not?

Comment: @JasonFB See also my edited answer. Perhaps this is an alternative for your problem..

Answer (score 4):

In a script with Rails loaded (e.g. `rails runner script.rb`)

```
def rake(*tasks)
  tasks.each do |task|
    Rake.application[task].tap(&:invoke).tap(&:reenable)
  end
end

rake('db:migrate', 'cache:clear', 'cache:warmup')
```