# How to call Rake tasks that are defined in the standard Rakefile from an other Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, rake

Is it possible to call a task which is defined in a `Rakefile` - not in `somefile.rake` - from an other Ruby script?

I was hoping that creating a new `Rake::Application` would automatically load the `Rakefile` from the same directory, but it seems that this is not the case. Here is what I came up with so far:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)
require 'rake'
require 'pp'

rake = Rake::Application.new
rake[:hello].invoke
```

Executing this code results in the following:

```
/opt/ruby/1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1720:in `[]': Don't know how to build task 'hello' (RuntimeError)
from script.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

`pp rake` yields the following:

```
#<Rake::Application:0x00000101118da0
 @default_loader=#<Rake::DefaultLoader:0x00000101118b20>,
 @imported=[],
 @last_description=nil,
 @loaders=
  {".rb"=>#<Rake::DefaultLoader:0x00000101118a80>,
   ".rf"=>#<Rake::DefaultLoader:0x000001011189b8>,
   ".rake"=>#<Rake::DefaultLoader:0x00000101118800>},
 @name="rake",
 @original_dir=
  "/Users/t6d/Projects/Sandbox/Ruby/rake-from-ruby-script",
 @pending_imports=[],
 @rakefile=nil,
 @rakefiles=["rakefile", "Rakefile", "rakefile.rb", "Rakefile.rb"],
 @rules=[],
 @scope=[],
 @tasks={},
 @top_level_tasks=[],
 @tty_output=false>
```

It is somehow irritating that `@rakefile` is `nil`.

*Update May 20th, 4:40pm CET*

After reading the rake source code for a little while, I figured out that you need to call Rake::Application#init in order to initialize your newly created rake application:

```
rake = Rake::Application.new
rake.init
rake.load_rakefile
```

However, I still cannot invoke any tasks defined in my Rakefile:

```
rake.top_level_tasks # => ["default"]
```

I'd gladly appreciate any help on that matter.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530/how-do-i-rake-tasks-within-a-ruby-script too

Comment: FWIW, that link tells how to run one task, by constructing the application, the script will behave more like the `rake` executable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You forgot to add your new `rake` to the current Rake Application:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)

require 'rake'
require 'pp'

rake = Rake::Application.new
Rake.application = rake
rake.init
rake.load_rakefile

rake[:hello].invoke
```

or just

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)
require 'rake'
require 'pp'

Rake.application.init
Rake.application.load_rakefile

Rake.application[:hello].invoke
```

Comment: Genius and right on time. I was starting to think that I might have to use something like `system rake ...`, but now I can use this much cleaner solution of yours. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great solution, though it needs modifying slightly to support tasks with arguments. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858495/ruby-accessing-rake-task-from-a-gem-without-rails/13860134

Answer (score 11):

Just load the Rakefile:

```
==> foo.rb <==
require 'rubygems'
require 'rake'

load 'Rakefile'

Rake::Task[:some_task].invoke

==> Rakefile <==
task :some_task do
  puts "some_task"
end
```

Rake::Application is all about command-line processing, default rakefiles, output, etc.  You might not need any of that.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. I assumed the Rakefile would be loaded by default in Rails but it's not.