# bin stub - missing dependencies from gem (executing rake tasks within gem)

Tags: rubygems, rake, rakefile

I've written a gem [elastic-beanstalk](https://github.com/alienfast/elastic-beanstalk) which is to be used inside a rails project file structure, as well as in a standalone CI environment where the rails dir and files are not available (without unzipping etc).  i.e. the Bamboo build process running `eb:package` will yield one primary artifact `app.zip` where the deploy plan at a later time and perhaps on another agent can take over and execute `eb:deploy`.

#### The goal

This is all running fine when inside a rails project structure, so my goal here is to also get this running for the standalone CI environment.

#### Given

an empty dir (CI environment) with just the `app.zip`, `eb.yml`, binstubs created, and the gem is available

#### When

I run `elastic-beanstalk eb:deploy`

#### Then

it should run the equivalent of `rake eb:deploy` using this gem's dependencies and lib files.

### Update - Bin Stub

It appears that a bin stub may be what I'm looking for.  Exploring [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858495/ruby-accessing-rake-task-from-a-gem-without-rails?rq=1), I have tried (to no avail so far) `bin/elastic-beanstalk`:

```
gem_dir = File.expand_path('..',File.dirname(__FILE__))
$LOAD_PATH.unshift gem_dir# Look in gem directory for resources first.

lib = File.expand_path('lib', gem_dir)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)

require 'elastic/beanstalk'
require 'rake'
require 'pp'

pwd=Dir.pwd
Dir.chdir("#{gem_dir}/bin") # We'll load rakefile from the gem's bin dir.
Rake.application.init
Rake.application.load_rakefile
Dir.chdir(pwd) # Revert to original pwd for any path args passed to task.

Rake.application.invoke_task(ARGV[0])
```

So this runs, but is still failing with the same dependency problem I began with `undefined method 'safe_load_file' for Psych:Module (NoMethodError)`.  While I think a binstub is the way to go:

### How can I resolve the dependency problem with the bin stub?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, I needed a call to `Bundler.setup` to resolve dependencies.

After cleanup, the file below is the only thing I needed to call a rake task with a bin file inside a gem (external bin stub utilizes this file):

### bin/elastic-beanstalk

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rake'
require 'bundler'

raise "Bundler is required.  Please install bundler with 'gem install bundler'" unless defined?(Bundler)

#
# Example:
#
#   elastic-beanstalk eb:show_config
#   elastic-beanstalk eb:show_config[1.1.1]
#

# init dependencies
Bundler.setup

# init rake
Rake.application.init

# load the rake tasks
gem_dir = File.expand_path('..',File.dirname(__FILE__))
load "#{gem_dir}/lib/elastic/beanstalk/tasks/eb.rake"

# invoke the given task
Rake.application.invoke_task(ARGV[0])
```