# How to write and execute an individual rake task outside the Rails application folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

How do you write a rake task outside the Rails application directory and make it run.

For example, say write a sample rake task

```
task :dummy do
  puts User.first.first_name
end
```

this task is under `~/fun/sample.rake`

And my rails application is located at `~/my_app/`

Now I need to run the sample.rake. I know i need to load the environment, DB etc., etc., how do i do that? Stuck at this for the past hour.

I tried the one below, obviously it did not work because it did not know how to build it.

```
rake -f ~/my_app/Rakefile dummy
```

Note: I should not touch the files inside the Rails application but I can write whatever I want inside the fun directory

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a Rakefile and load the rake gem. See this answer: [Ruby: Accessing rake task from a gem without Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858495/ruby-accessing-rake-task-from-a-gem-without-rails)