# How can I run a rake task in ROR application code without calling it in a new gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, task, rake-task

I am new to Ruby so forgive me if my question is obvious. I would really appreciate a little help here.

I have a project which I use as a library. It has 2 rake tasks which gives me a new file which is stored in a folder in the project. Let's say that this rake task serves as a parser and gives a JSON file.

This project can also be used as a gem. The .rake files are placed in the lib path of the project, so the rake tasks are publicly available.

I would like to call this rake tasks in my ruby code, in a new ROR application and have access to the outputed JSON file.

How I can run a rake tasks from a gem in my ROR application code and how I can have access to a file that is stored in the inner folder of the gem?

Comment: You can call rake tasks by calling `Rake::Task['your_task_name'].invoke(your,task,args)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby: Accessing rake task from a gem without Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858495/ruby-accessing-rake-task-from-a-gem-without-rails)

Comment: @MrYoshiji. The statement you wrote can also be used for the Rake Tasks of a Gem? Because the application where the gem is included does not have rake tasks.

Comment: Doesn't work for tasks inside of Gems