# Running Rake tasks in Rspec Tests

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd, rake

I am building up an integration test suite and there is one bit of logic that I need to have a clean database for. How can I run the `db:test:purge` task inside of one of my tests?

I am using: ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.0.9, rspec 2.6

Comment: same without RSpec: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530/how-do-i-rake-tasks-within-a-ruby-script

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can invoke Rake tasks as following:

```
require 'rake'
Rake::Task[name].invoke
```

In this case this would result in the following code:

```
require 'rake'
Rake::Task['db:test:purge'].invoke
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks. I also had the name of the task wrong, which was throwing me off at first. In Rails 3, rake test:prepare seemed to do the trick

Comment: @jim good point. you can use <code>Rake::Task[name].execute</code> in those instances, but you will need to make sure that you satisfy any of it's dependencies (e.g. `:environment`) since those aren't run when calling the task with this method.

Comment: This was helpful. How does one pass parameters into the task give the examples above?

Comment: I think loading the tasks would be necessary sometimes by calling `MyRailsApp::Application.load_tasks`

Comment: @egezer Using `MyRailsApp::Application.load_tasks` led me to test pollution issues where my rake tasks would be invoked multiple times if `load_tasks` had already been called earlier in the test suite. Using `Rake.application.rake_require` along with `Rake::Task.define_task(:environment)` avoided this issue.

Comment: @egezer Very helpful.

Comment: Note that invoke will **only run the task once** (per `load_tasks`). Use `execute` to run more than once.

Answer (score 38):

Approved answer didn't work for me, when I needed to execute my own rake task

Here's my solution

Put in the top of the spec file

```
require 'rake'
```

Place these lines where you need to execute your custom rake task, e.g. **rake update_data** from the file **example.rake**

```
load File.expand_path("../../../lib/tasks/example.rake", __FILE__)
# make sure you set correct relative path 
Rake::Task.define_task(:environment)
Rake::Task["update_data"].invoke
```

My environment:

```
rails (4.0.0)
ruby (2.0.0p195)
rspec-core (2.14.7) 
rspec-expectations (2.14.3) 
rspec-mocks (2.14.4) 
rspec (2.14.1) 
rspec-rails (2.14.0)
```

Comment: Hii, instead i have used _Rails.application.load_tasks_, below require 'rake'. Is this a good solution?

Comment: `Rake::Task.define_task(:environment)` for the win in avoiding `RuntimeError: Don't know how to build task 'environment' (see --tasks)`

Comment: I'm using:  `Rake.application.rake_require "tasks/task-name"` to load the specific task being tested, instead of loading all of them with `Rails.application. load_tasks`  (Rails 5, Rspec 3.5)

Answer (score 18):

If we require to use multiple rake tasks we can add

```
require "rake"
Rails.application.load_tasks
```

Then simply call any task.

```
Rake::Task['sync:process_companies'].invoke
```

Though I cant confirm if its slower because it loads all the tasks

Comment: Using `Rails.application.load_tasks` led me to test pollution issues where my rake tasks would be invoked multiple times if `load_tasks` had already been called earlier in the same suite. Using the above solutions avoided this issue.

Answer (score 4):

for me (rails-6)

```
Rails.application.load_tasks
Rake::Task['app:sync'].invoke
```

=> require not necnessary in my case

Answer (score 4):

Many of the above answers worked for me for running a single spec. However, I had to take an extra step when running multiple specs for a single rake task.

After each spec, I had to run `Rake::Task.clear`, as  (for some reason) the task would not be run again if it was registered as being `already_invoked` (i.e. if `Rake::Task['my_task'].already_invoked` returned `true`.

I added the following line to my rake task spec:

```
after { Rake::Task.clear }
```

and everything worked as expected when running multiple tests for the same rake task.

Comment: There is `Rake::Task#reenable`

Answer (score 2):

We need to require the task also

```
require 'rake'
Rake.application.rake_require 'tasks/new_adapter'
```

After this, just call the task

```
Rake::Task['new:adapter'].invoke
```