# How do I run multiple Rake tasks programmatically at once?

Tags: ruby, rake

At the command line I can run multiple tasks like this

```
rake environment task1 task2 task3
```

How can I do this programmatically? I know that I can run one task like this

```
Rake::Task['task1'].invoke
```

Comment: You can't call the `invoke` line more than once?

Comment: answers to the following imply answers to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530/how-do-i-rake-tasks-within-a-ruby-script

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can call two tasks:

```
require 'rake'

task :task1 do |t|
  p t
end
task :task2 do |t|
  p t
end


Rake::Task["task1"].invoke
Rake::Task["task2"].invoke
```

I would prefer a new tast with prerequisites:

```
require 'rake'

task :task1 do |t|
  p t
end
task :task2 do |t|
  p t
end
desc "Common task"
task :all => [ :task1, :task2  ]
Rake::Task["all"].invoke
```

If I misunderstood your question and you want to execute the same task twice: You can `reenable` tasks:

```
require 'rake'

task :task1 do |t|
  p t
end
Rake::Task["task1"].invoke
Rake::Task["task1"].reenable
Rake::Task["task1"].invoke
```

Comment: yup, i guess i just needed to invoke two tasks one after the other.

Comment: You can also use `.execute` instead of `.invoke` if you are running the same rake task multiple times. `invoke` will only allow it to be called once unless you use `reenable`.

Answer (score 2):

Make a rake task for it :P

```
# in /lib/tasks/some_file.rake
namespace :myjobs do 
  desc "Doing work, son" 
  task :do_work => :environment do
    Rake::Task['resque:work'].invoke 
    start_some_other_task
  end

  def start_some_other_task
    # custom code here
  end
end
```

Then just call it:

```
rake myjobs:do_work
```

Comment: I was hoping to do it without creating additional rake tasks. I'm not running from the command line at all, so I would have to Rake::Task['myjobs:do_work'].invoke. I will try this.

Comment: `Rake::Task['myjobs:do_work'].invoke` works as well.  Just nice to consolidate things, IMO. Easier to maintain in the future