# Run rake task in cucumber hooks.rb

Tags: cucumber, rake

I have a situation where I need to invoke a rake task in AfterConfiguration in Cucumber hooks.rb file. At the moment when I tried to invoke Rake task I get following error

'Don't know how to build task rake db:test_seed'

I m using rails 3.2.2

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I came here wanting to know the answer to this in a general context -- it's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530/how-do-i-rake-tasks-within-a-ruby-script (not optimized for rails but it should be fine)